# How to add second word as a number of each line in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to add all the money

```
$ cat samplemoney.txt
Company1 100
Company2 200
Company3 100
Company4 300
Company5 200
```

Following is the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
sum=0;
while read l;
do
IFS=' ' read -r -a array<<< "$l"
a=${array[1]}
sum=`expr $sum+$a`
done<samplemoney.txt
echo $sum
```

Output Getting:

```
0+100+200+100+300
```

Output required:

```
900
```

**NOTE - Using Git Bash on Windows**

Comment: You did not write how you are invoking the script, but if you are running it by just entering the script name, it does not use bash, but sh.  In case you indeed do run it as bash (by entering `bash scriptname`), the addition can be written simpler as `((sum+=a))`. If you prefer to stick with `expr` for whatever reason, you need spaces around the `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`while` can read directly from the file (ie, no need for an array), eg:

```
sum=0

while read -r company amount
do
    (( sum+=amount ))
done < samplemoney.txt

echo "${sum}"
```

**NOTES:**

- `sum+=amount` works as long as you're dealing with integers; if you find you need to work with reals/floats then it gets a bit more complicated from a `bash` perspective (though William Pursell's `awk` solution should work for both integers and reals/floats)
- the `(( sum+=amount ))` requires `bash` (eg, `#!/bin/bash`); while OP's code shows `#!/bin/sh` (which I assume is bourne shell), the question is also tagged with `bash` (which I take to mean OP also has access to `bash`)

This generates:

```
900
```

---

OP is having problems running this in `git/bash` on windows, getting the error:

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

This appears to be an issue with Windows line endings (`\r`) in the data file.

OP has a few options:

- run `dos2unix samplemoney.txt` (to remove the `\r`'s) before running the `while` loop or ...
- replace `while read -r` with `while IFS=$IFS$'\r' read -r` (per Gordon Davisson's comment) or ...
- replace `done < samplemoney.txt` with `done < <(tr -d '\r' < samplemoney.txt)`

Comment: I am getting this - $ ./addmoneysc.sh
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
0

Comment: @RupeshKumar  sorry, just noticed your script is using `#!/bin/sh` (I'm assuming this is bourne shell); you've tagged the question with `bash` as well (which I take to mean you have access to `bash`) so ... can you try with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Thanks for the info. The reason I wanted an iterative approach is that it would be more clear to solve the actual question mention in the comment of the Williams answer

Comment: @RupeshKumar sure, understood; I've updated the answer to show you can read the company name with `while`; from here you could add a test (inside the loop) for company name before adding `amount` to `sum`; and in case William doesn't see your comment/question ... yes, you could use `awk` to only add up the numbers for a given company; if William doesn't respond with an update then you may want to create a new question with the new requirement

Comment: I tried with / bash the error is still the same. I am using git bash on windows. Thanks

Comment: hmmmm, would need to see the exact text of your script

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GBLEzaWnTUUt5rI1el_Y4Qqmc61k1mpI?usp=sharing

Comment: good news: I can reproduce this error; the issue: windows line endings (`\r`) is screwing with the data; a quick fix is to remove the `\r's` (eg, `dos2unix samplemoney.txt`); if you don't have `dos2unix` then try `done < <(tr -d '\r' < samplemoney.txt)`; I'll update the answer with these details

Comment: Another possible fix for Windows line endings in the input file: `while IFS=$IFS$'\r' read -r ...`

Answer (score 6):

This is almost trivial with awk:

```
$ cat money.txt 
Company1 100
Company2 200
Company3 100
Company4 300
Company5 200
$ awk '{s += $2} END {print s}' money.txt 
900
```

Comment: Thanks, If there would be same companies occurring multiple times i.e (Company1 200 again Company 1 300)and I have to add all the money of company one. Can I do that with awk?

Comment: @RupeshKumar Very easily.  Something like: `awk '{a[$1]+= $2} END {for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' money.txt`

Comment: Thanks for this. Also, there is an [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766072/write-a-script-command-to-find-the-total-cost-incurred-by-company1/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a minor typo: add spaces to "`expr $sum+$a`" and your code 'works':

```
cat sample_money.txt
Company1 100
Company2 200
Company3 100
Company4 300
Company5 200

cat add_script.sh
#!/bin/sh
sum=0;
while read l
do
  IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$l"
  a=${array[1]}
  sum=`expr $sum + $a`
done < sample_money.txt
echo $sum

./add_script.sh
900
```

Having said that, you have a number of issues that should be addressed e.g. no need to use an array, outdated/antiquated syntax; consider using a linter such as shellcheck.net to improve your code.

Comment: $ ./addmoneysc.sh
expr: non-integer argument
expr: non-integer argument
300

Comment: $ cat addmoneysc.sh
#!/bin/sh
sum=0;
while read l
do
  IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$l"
  a=${array[1]}
  sum=`expr $sum + $a`
done < samplemoney.txt
echo $sum

Comment: There's no need to use `expr`. Even POSIX shells support `sum=$(( $sum + $a ))`.