# Write a script command to find the total cost incurred by Company1

Tags: sh

Given the contents of the file as follow:

```
Company1 400
Company2 500
Company3 600
Company2 150
Company1 350
```

Write a script command to find the total cost incurred by Company1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` is well suited to this:

```
awk '$1 == "Company1"{sum += $2} END {print sum}' money.txt
```

`awk` processes the input file(s) one line at a time, splitting the fields on whitespace.  In this script, the second column of all lines in which the first column exactly matches the string `Company1` are added to the variable `sum`.  At the end, the sum is printed.

It is easy to parameterize by doing something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
    
company=${1-Company1}
    
awk 'tolower($1) == tolower(c) {sum += $2}
    END {print sum}' c="$company" money.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation. I think awk is well suited here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
check="Company1" 
while read -r checkin amount;
do
    if [[ "$checkin" == "$check"  ]];
    then
        (( sum+=amount ))
    fi
done < <(tr -d '\r' < money.txt)

echo "${sum}"
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765435/how-to-add-second-word-as-a-number-of-each-line-in-a-file/)